Home Energy Assessment
How do you get information about optimizing your home in terms of energy efficiency in the US? I can't figure out what the best solution is, and I always feel like contractors I talk to are trying to push what they want on me.
Do you know of any comprehensive solutions online so that I can form my own opinion between windows , pellet stoves, insulation, heat pumps, pv panels etc., in terms of cost savings, initial investment, and ecological impact?
cheers

Often times your local energy providers will offer free energy audits of their customers.  These audits will often provide guidance on recommended improvements to help reduce energy usage.  These recommendations could include all sorts of options such as better exterior insulation, replacement windows, furnace/ac replacements, or other energy savings options.  Best of all, these free audits typically have no hidden agenda other than to try and reduce your energy consumption.
Once the audit has been completed, you can take their specific recommendations and act on those with contractors in those specific areas, depending on your budget potential cost savings over the long term.

Aside of getting energy audit from your energy provider you can do some work your self.
You will need note pad a pen and cheap handheld infrared thermometer.
First open the circuit breakers panel and look for large circuit breakers. Those are usually the Air Conditioning, the Dryer, the Oven and EV charger as your largest energy consumers. Some like Dryer and EV charger can be run overnight when the electricity rate is lower.
Next use the thermometer and measure and make notes. During sun exposure the inner wall, the doors and windows and the ceiling. That would give you a thermal map. Assuming the windows are double or triple glazed. If you do the measurements without AC running, the delta from outside too inside should be 15-20 F indicating good insulation.
